# Pandas read_csv end reading at first linebreak

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read a csv file with some garbage at the top, but also garbage at the bottom of the interesting data. I need to read multiple files and the length of the interesting data varies. Is there a way to let the `pd.read_csv` command know that the dataframe ends at the first linebreak?

Example data (screenshot from excel):
[image: example data]

I read the file with:
`dataframe = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows=45)`
Which nicely gives me a dataframe with 10 columns with the headers on line 46 (see image). However, it continues further than the #GARBAGE DATA row.

Important note: Neither the length of the data nor the length of the footer is of equal length in the different files I want to read.

Comment: just drop all rows after an empty row

Answer (score 1):

Two ways you could implement this

1) use skipfooter parameter of read csv , it tells the function the Number of lines at bottom of file to skip

```
pd.read_csv("in.csv",skiprows=45,skipfooter=2)
```

2) Read the file as it is and later use dropna function, this should drop the Garbage values.

```
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

Comment: you can't use the first solution since the length of the footer isnt constant and you cant just drop all nan values since there can be nans in the dataframe itself

Comment: you can easily modify the solution to only look for specific columns and then dropna's. If the data and files are so dynamic you could then right a script to loop through the file and remove the unwanted lines. I feel the solution given should suffice. in case not we can look to modify it based on what data we are expecting as input

Answer (score 0):

After using this command:

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows=45)
```

You can use this command:

```
dataframe= dataframe.dropna(how='any')
```

This would delete a row if any empty value has been found in that row. Hence it would delete rest of all the rows.

Comment: `LevelCode` doesn't have values, too. So it would drop every row

Comment: In that case, take all columns that you're sure which won't have empty values. Then apply,  (dataframe= dataframe.dropna(how='any', subset=[list of all those columns]))